# Change the Filter in Kendo.Grid to Use Text instead of Bound Value associated w/Column

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In my Kendo.Grid I have:

```
columns.Bound(c => c.FORMRIGHTTYPEID).Width("25").Title("Form Right").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "text-align: center;" })
  .Template(@<text>
    @if (item.FORMRIGHTTYPEID != null)
    {
      @DisplayRight((long)item.FORMRIGHTTYPEID)
    }
    </text>);
```

Note that I am displaying a text value associated w/the FORMRIGHTTYPEID numeric value.  I have made the grid "Filterable":

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<EPIMS.Models.FORMRIGHTS>()

...

...

.Scrollable()
.Groupable()
.Sortable()
.Filterable(filterable => filterable
            .Extra(false)
            .Operators(operators => operators
            .ForString(str => str.Clear()
            .Contains("Contains")
)))
.Pageable(pageable => pageable
.Refresh(true)
.PageSizes(true)
.ButtonCount(5))
.BindTo(Model))
```

My problem is that the Filter option shows "Show items with value that: Is equal to" but does not allow me to enter text.  Rather (and as expected), the value MUST BE numeric as the column is bound to a numeric value field.

Is it possible to customize the Filter?

Thanks

Comment: I did a little research and testing on one of my apps.  I haven't found a way to do this yet, unfortunately.  My "hacky" recommendation would be to update your view model to add same property as a string, and then bind that column to the grid.  I know not ideal, but it would work.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.  i was hoping to not have to go about it in that way.  The Telerik guys suggested I look at this demo:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/filter-menu-customization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented a stored procedure that returns the ID and DESCRIPTION field associated w/the numeric value.  Basically, what @mmillican suggested to do (i.e. change the view model).